# PHP - different database type (PDO or what)?

Tags: sql-server, mysqli, pdo

I am working in a company that is about to start a web project. However, at this stage we are not sure about the database type. We may even let potential app user decide what database to use. Until than I have to start with something.

So lets imagine I need to consider MySQL(i), MSSQL, SQLite or similar. What approach would be best in order to be able to switch to different database via simple config file update? Is that PDO or what?

Thank you.

Comment: The best link to use would be [PHP: PDO Drivers](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.drivers.php) this shows all the drivers available to `PDO` and how to format the `connection string`

Answer (score 1):

Different DBMS systems using different SQL syntax. For example, explore theme of `LIMIT` in MySQL, PostgreSQL, MS SQL Server. So, you may use abstraction above SQL. Use one of query builders or ORM library. Your choose will depend on architecture of your project.

Answer (score 0):

PDO advantage is being compatible with most database.

If you ever decide to change database type, you won't have to change your code, just the connection.